# Is there any way to use string in c++ without the word "string" appear in the program?

Tags: c++, string, syntax

As title stated, is there any way of doing that?
I tried to use #define, and #typedef but both will require the word "string" to appear in the program.

Comment: hmmm maybe `char *`?

Comment: You can use cstrings.

Comment: While *is it possible* questions can be fun I see no practical programming problem this could solve.

Comment: Which are technically `const char *` but Amadeus's suggestion of `char *` works just as well.

Comment: What is `#typedef`?

Comment: Please define "appear" and "program" as you use them in this context.

Comment: Yes, write your own string class and name it something useful like "multiple_text" or "taco".

Comment: What would be the use case for this? Are you trying to cheat some online judge or grading program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
#define S str##ing
#define S_INCLUDE <S>

#include <iostream>
#include S_INCLUDE

int main()
{
    std::S str = "Hello world!";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::runtime_error("").what()` returns a `const char *` so it is not a `std:stirng`.

Comment: Note that the fact that `<string>` is not required to be in `<iostream>`...

Answer (score 3):

You can use macro:

```
#define CO( first, second ) second##first

int main()
{
    CO( ing, str ) foobar;
}
```

which produces this error:

```
error: ‘string’ was not declared in this scope
     CO( ing, str ) foobar;
```

this shows that literal `string` was built, using it as a type is obvious (through `using namespace std` or changing `str` to `std::str`).

if you have c++14 you can use literals:

```
using namespace std::literals;
auto str = ""s;
decltype(str) anotherstr;
```

both solutions require header `<string>` but that can be avoided by including another system header, that directly or indirectly includes it.

but I do not really see any practical purpose of this.

Comment: You have to fix include for `std::literals` though.

Comment: The first answer produces an error I don't see how that is relevant. In the second answer you need `#include <string>` anyway.

Comment: in gcc you can just `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, if non-portability is allowed.

Comment: @imreal error shows that I built literal `string` successfully, using it without error is obvious. `#include <string>` can be avoided by including another system header than includes it.

Comment: @Slava might want to add that to the answer then

Comment: @imreal added, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Slava +1 upvoted

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#include FOOBAR_I

int main() {
    std::FOOBAR foobar = "";
    (void)foobar;
}
```

And compile it with the following command line parameters:

```
-DFOOBAR="string" -DFOOBAR_I="<string>"
```